# Two authoryear-style citation call-outs with text in between

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using `natbib` to format my references. I know how to add text to citations using

`\citep[e.g.][](Darwin_origin_1859)`

But now I would like to have say something like this:

`some more text (Darwin, 1859, but see Carroll 1865)`

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The citation call-out macros of the `natbib` package let you place a `\cite`-like instruction inside the optional argument of another `\cite`-like instruction.

E.g., assuming the bibliographic entries have keys `darwin` and `carroll`, your typographic objective can be met by writing

```
\citep[but see \citealt{carroll}]{darwin}
```

A more tedious way to obtain the same output might be:

```
\citetext{\citealp{darwin}, but see \citealt{darwin}}
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{darwin, author="Charles Darwin", year=1859}
@misc{carroll,author="Lewis Carroll",  year=1865}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % select a suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\noindent
\dots\ \citep[but see \citealt{carroll}]{darwin} \dots
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```